# Datasheet view editable?

Tags: list-view

I have a column that is set up as a calculated column. I can change that column in standard view with no problems, but when I switch to datasheetview and click in the box the calculation comes up and won't let me insert what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit calculated and read-only colums (like Created By) in edit and datasheet view. You can also remove colums from standart views but datasheet view will show you every column. But you can enter data to other columns and press enter so calculated column value must be shown as read-only.